# Wireless Bridge setup NVG510/WRT54G

Tags: networking

I have to use a NVG510 to connect to AT&T, I want to use a DDWRT router to connect to the NVG510 via wireless, I want my devices Ipad, Firestick, Iphone to connect to the DDWRT via wireless,,is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it's possible!**
You can connect two routers together over wireless in many ways:

1. **Without ddwrt firmware**

**WDS:** is a mesh network, Routers must have the SAME chip-set type for WDS to work. So If you want the easiest way without changing the firmware you can use this method, but don't forget to buy the same model like the first router, and check if your first router support WDS befure you buy anything!

2. **With ddwrt firmware**

**Repeater or Bridge:**
You only need the secondary router with dd-wrt firmware, Your second router will only boost the signal "DHCP & NAT disabled"

You can find step by step tutorial [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge)

**Client or Client Bridge:**

1. Client Bridged: All computers can see one another in Windows Network.
2. Client Mode: Computers on one wired network can not see computers on other wired network in Windows Network

   You can find step by step tutorial [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged)